# Body content in HTML

Tags: html, css

[![enter image description here][1]][1]The body content is showing below the sidebar instead of in the middle. I'm relatively new to web implementing sidebar and  I'm not sure where I have gone wrong. I want my body to be in the middle of the page (next to the sidebar and below the top bar)

```html
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" style="margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; margin-top:0px;">
  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <img src="logo.png" height="20%" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="1.png" height="12.5%" style="width:900%">
      </div>

      <div class="topnav" style="; width:90%; height:12.5% margin-left:10%">
        <a style="padding:12px;" href="home.html">Home</a>
        <a style="padding:12px;" class="active" href="tutorials.html">Tutorials</a>
        <a style="padding:12px;" href="fitness.html">Fitness</a>
        <a style="padding:12px;" href="fashion.html">Fashion</a>
      </div>
    </div>


    <h1 style="margin:0px;padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; background-color:#000000; width:10%; color: #cbcbfd; font-family:fantasy;; font-size:1.2em;">C</h1>
    <h1 style="margin:0px;padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:3px; background-color:#000000; width:10%; color: #b6b6fc; font-family:serif; font-size:1em;">&nbspGetting Started</h1>
    <div class="sidenav" style="width:10%; ">
      <a style="color:#9898fb; font-family:serif; font-size:0.75em;padding:3px;padding-left:20px" href="">Why C</a>
      <a style="color:#9898fb; font-family:serif; font-size:0.75em;padding:3px;padding-left:20px" href="">History of C</a>
      <a style="color:#9898fb; font-family:serif; font-size:0.75em;padding:3px;padding-left:20px" href="">Features of C</a>
      <a style="color:#9898fb; font-family:serif; font-size:0.75em;padding:3px;padding-left:20px" href="">Installing C</a>
    </div>

    <h1 style="margin:0px;padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:3px; background-color:#000000; width:10%; color: #b6b6fc; font-family:serif; font-size:1em;">Something</h1>
    <div class="sidenav" style="width:10%; ">
      <a style="color:#9898fb; font-family:serif; font-size:0.75em;padding:3px;padding-left:20px" href="">A</a>
      <a style="color:#9898fb; font-family:serif; font-size:0.75em;padding:3px;padding-left:20px" href="">B</a>
      <a style="color:#9898fb; font-family:serif; font-size:0.75em;padding:3px;padding-left:20px" href="">C</a>
      <a style="color:#9898fb; font-family:serif; font-size:0.75em;padding:3px;padding-left:20px" href="">D</a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <p style="center:15%;">Why</p>
</body>
```

[image]

Updated Error https://ibb.co/ThhbbWk

Comment: side-note: take some time to read about CSS classes, because you have many `a` tags that you use the same CSS properties and write it over and over again, assign a class to the element and write the CSS only once, it will be much better for you

Comment: By default, `div` tags are displayed as `block` elements; which means they can't be placed next to each other without additional CSS. Adding `float:left;` to your `sidenav` class should work. I would also look into creating a separate CSS file and using that instead of inline styles, as it gets very hard to read.

Comment: You could have a look at the [Basic concepts of flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox). It provides a number of intuitive style definitions to position elements easily. Besides, you should better use a CSS document instead of all your inline stylings.

Comment: `bgcolor` has been obsolete for many years.

Comment: the images you post here are different from what we see in the snippet. Please, take a look in [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a container for your sidenav and your content. It's better to use class .
To create a sideNav you can use position: fixed. it's relative to the viewport,  it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled.

Here a simple example:
HTML file:

```
<div class="sidenav">Your sideNav</div>
<div class="content">Your content</div>
```

CSS file:

```
.sidenav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  background: grey;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Comment: could you give me the code ? in codepen or stackblitz please

Comment: have a look please

Comment: i tried your method but didnt work so removed it and sent

Comment: Some advices: Remove all your style in html file, use class instead. You don't need to wrap each link group with sidenav class, instead wrap all sidenav elements with only one div.sidenav. The h1 element is used to indicate the most important heading on the page  (just for 'c++' header maybe in your example)
The other titles should be less important (like h2,h3).For your content use a div tag not p ( p is used for paragraph not container)

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that both your `sidenav` and `<p>` tags are displayed as `block` by default.

Either give them a fixed width or `display: inline-block` and `float: left` in order to fix this.